# Shortcut ctrl + space

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I solve the issue of the Ctrl + Space shortcut not working in Android Studio before typing the first character, but it works when typing at least one character?

By default, when I press this shortcut, it should show me suggestions for writing, but they don't appear. I have to type at least one character for the shortcut to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why did Ctrl+Space (Autocomplete) suddenly stop working in Android Studio, Intellij, and other JetBrains IDEs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76444491/why-did-ctrlspace-autocomplete-suddenly-stop-working-in-android-studio-intel)

Answer (score -1):

This was driving me crazy too.  Check the answer on this other post and see if you might be having the same problem:

[Why did Ctrl+Space (Autocomplete) suddenly stop working in Android Studio, Intellij, and other JetBrains IDEs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76444491/why-did-ctrlspace-autocomplete-suddenly-stop-working-in-android-studio-intel/76444492#76444492)

TL;DR - If you use Windows PowerToys, try disabling Peek.  Answer includes steps and screenshots.

Comment: please don't answer duplicates. wait for your other answer to get upvoted or accepted, and thin vote this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @starball, this was a bit of an odd case because this question existed before mine so it really isn't a "duplicate".  My answer was specifically about a conflict between PowerToys and Ctrl+Space shortcut and this question doesn't mention PowerToys, but I had a suspicion it could be related because of the timing, but I landed here first while hunting for an answer to my own problem.

It might be fine to mark this as a possible dupe.