# Why did Ctrl+Space (Autocomplete) suddenly stop working in Android Studio, Intellij, and other JetBrains IDEs?

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, jetbrains-ide, windows-11

**I noticed that `Ctrl + Space` had stopped giving me autocomplete suggestions.**

I had to delete the preceding code and start typing again to get any autocomplete suggestions.  At first I thought it was related to suggestions from GitHub CoPilot, but disabling didn't help.

The strangest thing was that when I went to check if the keymap had been messed up, `Ctrl + Space` would not be detected, but `Ctrl + Shift + Space` would.

[image: JetBrains Shortcut search by keystroke]

You can use this tool to check if you're having the same problem in the IDE by opening Settings > Keymap > Click the Magnifying Glass  with the little keys on it on the right, then see if anything shows up when you hit `Ctrl + Space` if it doesn't but other keys combinations do work, you've likely got the same problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit:** As of July 2023, PowerToys has addressed this bug and now Ctrl+Space is only captured in File Explorer rather than system wide, so if upgrading your power toys installation is an option, v0.70.1 works.  If not, follow the instructions below to disable the feature with a conflicting hotkey.

## **Disable PowerToys new Peek feature that uses `Ctrl + Space`**

After a while and not finding answers easily from searching (even saw a bug report on JetBrains bug tracker) I found the cause.

I had recently upgraded **PowerToys**, a Windows utility that gives a bunch of powerful tools like a color picker, and bulk file rename capabilities, window snapping regions, etc.

The updated added a new feature called **Peek**.  When you have a text file selected in the File Browser, you can press `Ctrl + Space` to open a preview of the file.  Because PowerToys is watching for this shortcut at an OS level, it never makes it to other Applications running.

To disable the feature and get your Autocomplete back, simply:

### Open PowerToys from the system tray

[image: PowerToys icon in the task tray]

### Click `More >`

[image: PowerToys More Button]

### Scroll down and toggle off **Peek**.

[image: Peek Toggle]

Comment: They should have warned us. This affected way too many people...

Comment: @PunkyMunky64 seriously!  Ctrl+Space has to be the most common shortcut I've used in the last 15 years.  Hiding that at the OS level is definitely an oversight.  It would make much more sense for +Space to be the shortcut since most PowerToys keybinds use the Windows key anyway so this hasn't been a problem.